# Filter Excel data on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I have the following Excel sheet that I want to filter:

| Id | Status | run |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COMPLETED | 2 |
| 1 | FAILED | 1 |
| 3 | FAILED | 1 |
| 3 | FAILED | 2 |
| 5 | COMPLETED | 3 |
| 6 | COMPLETED | 1 |
| 5 | FAILED | 1 |
| 5 | FAILED | 2 |
| 9 | COMPLETED | 1 |
| 7 | COMPLETED | 1 |

I want to get the rows where any `id` doesn't have a `COMPLETED` status and copy them to a new sheet. So for example, using the above table, the new table should only have the rows with id 3 since that one never got a `COMPLETED` status.

I'm new to Excel and I'm not sure where to start looking or what to search for to get a guide or documentation on what I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a helper column to your data.

Formula for cell D2, which counts the total number of Completed statuses for that row's ID.

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"COMPLETED",A:A,A2)
```

Drag down the formula and here's the Output:

| id | status | run | HELPER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COMPLETED | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | FAILED | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | FAILED | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | FAILED | 2 | 0 |
| 5 | COMPLETED | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | COMPLETED | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | FAILED | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | FAILED | 2 | 1 |
| 9 | COMPLETED | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | COMPLETED | 1 | 1 |

Then filter where Helper = 0.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your cursor inside the table
2. Go to insert ribbon
3. Add new Pivot Table

Then in pivot table fields, add id to the rows, status to columns and run to values
[image: 1]

You will get the following result

[image: 2]

Now you can copy the data to a new sheet and **paste it as VALUES**
Then with a simple filter you can get the null completed ids

Comment: Thank you for showing me Pivot Table. I didn't know about it so this is useful to understand.

Comment: No problem glad to help :) excel is a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
=FILTER(A2:C11,COUNTIFS(A2:A11,A2:A11,B2:B11,"COMPLETED")=0)
```

it spills out the entire output, so there is no need to extend or drag the formula down. Here is the output:

[image: output]

The steps are straightforward, but since you mentioned you are new to Excel, here is the logic explained: Basically `COUNTIFS` returns an array of the same number of rows as **Id** column. Counting the number of `COMPLETED` statuses per `id`. For the input sample, it returns:

```
1
1
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Now we just need to filter via `FILTER` for getting the rows with zero counts.

If you want to add the header, then:

```
=VSTACK(A1:C1,FILTER(A2:C11,COUNTIFS(A2:A11,A2:A11,B2:B11,"COMPLETED")=0))
```

Comment: Thank you for all the information. This was really helpful!